# Generate tiles using GPU

Tags: python, tiles, mapproxy, generate-tiles

I was wondering if anyone has tried already to utilise the GPU in tile generation? I have a quite big dataset so tile generation takes a while (especially on high zoom levels) even on a quite high spec machine (Xeon X5355, 24G RAM, NVIDIA Quadro FX 4600).

Geographic extent: [-10, 46, 4, 65] (EPSG:4326)
Zoom levels: 19

There are a couple of things out there (e.g. [gumpy](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/gnumpy.html)) that looks promising, however, I have not find any case studies or references.

I am using MapProxy at the moment, but I am open to any other solution as well.